# Why is this simple app returning a 500 error?

Tags: python, flask

I am getting an Internal Server error, and I'm not sure what the issue is.  `index.html` is in the same directory as the Python file.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    author = "Rick"
    name = "1st flask app"
    return render_template('index.html', author=author, name=name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{ author }}'s app</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>Hello {{ name }}!</h2>
    <p>Please show up on the page</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why am I getting a 500 error rather than my rendered template?

Comment: Please include the traceback from your console output or logfiles in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a directory called `templates` and put `index.html` in it.

You can get more information about errors by running in debug mode:

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create your app 
`app = Flask(__name__)`
you can also include the `template_folder` parameter to specify the folder that contains your templates. If you don't, `render_template` will look for them in the default folder called `templates`. If such folder doesn´t exist, or if your template can't be found inside it, you will get an internal server error 500 rather than your rendered template.